# Forcing Tensorflow's Tokenizer to include "Next line" char

Tags: python, tensorflow, tokenize

I am trying to use tensorflow to model Persian poetry. To do so, I need to include '\n' in my tokens. However, when I use `tokenizer()`, it does not include the next lines. Is it possible to for [tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) to include '\n'?

```
data = open(link + "/hafez.txt").readlines()  # removing the first two lines
data = data[2:]
data = ''.join(data)
corpus = data.lower().split("\n")
for c in corpus: # including \n in the text
    c += '\n'
# update the vocab based on the list of texts ( corpus) returns a dictionary
# of Vocabulary
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
print(tokenizer.word_index['\n'])
```

Now, we see the '\n' is not included.

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 tokenizer.word_index['\n'] 
>   KeyError: '\n'

However, I need this later so that my neural network will hopefully split the generated words by `'\n'`.

Comment: Did you read the docs you linked?  `__init__()` takes an argument `filters`.  `\n` is in filters.  redefine the string with out it.

Comment: Thank you. I think i need to use: filter = '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t' can I use regex or easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `'\n'` from the `filters` argument I think you'll get what you are looking for.

**Example**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

corpus = "it was the best of times, it was the worst of times"
corpus = [c + '\n' for c in corpus.split()]

filters_ = '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t'  # <= removed '\n'
my_tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(
    filters=filters_,
    char_level=True)

my_tokenizer.fit_on_text(corpus)
eol_idx = my_tokenizer.word_index['\n']

print(eol_idx)
#  1
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess in my case, since I wanted to use \n as a token. I had to have char_level=False, and simply added appended a OOV to each '\n' and reran the tokenizer.